# Typescript generics error when trying to flatten a 3D array

Tags: typescript, generics, types, promise

Previously, when dealing with batched `promises`, I was using the following approach:

```
const batchedPromises = new Array<any>()

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  batchedPromises.push(myPromise(i))
}

const settledPromises = await Promise.allSettled(batchedPromises)
const fulfilledPromises = settledPromises.filter(({ status }) => status == 'fulfilled').map((p) => (<any>p).value)
```

As I am dealing with this method several times in my code base, I created an `onlySettled` `function` which would filter for the settled `promises` and give me their values:

```
export function onlyFulfilled<T>(settledPromises: Array<PromiseSettledResult<T>>): Array<T> {
   const fulfilled = (<Array<PromiseFulfilledResult<T>>>(settledPromises.filter(({ status }) => status == 'fulfilled')))
   const values = fulfilled.map((v) => v.value)

  return values
}
```

So that now I can simply do

```
const settledPromises = await Promise.allSettled(batchedPromises)
let fulfilledPromises = onlyFulfilled(settledPromises)
```

This works perfectly fine. Now, if I log my `fulfilledPromises` to a request I made, I get the following results:

```
[
  [
    [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ],
    [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ], ...
  ]
]
```

The first brackets in the 3D `array` indicate that my batch only had 1 `promise` to execute, thus, if for instance the execution involved 2 `promises`, the results would look something like this:

```
[
  [
    [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ],
    [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ], ...
  ],
  [
    [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c'
    ], ...
  ]
]
```

This means that the values of my `PromiseFulfilledResult` `promises` are of type `<Array<Array<string>>` (the `T` `generic` in the `onlyFulfilled` `function`).

Now let's suppose that I would like to be more type specific, enforcing the `generic` upon the `onlyFulfilled` `function` call:

```
let fulfilledPromises = onlyFulfilled<Array<Array<string>>>(settledPromises)
```

This works, fine, until I run `fulfilledPromises.flat()` in order to get all the values from different `promises` into a single `array`.

The error I get is the following

```
Type 'string[][]' is not assignable to type 'string[][][]'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[][]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

EDIT:

Is it because of instantiating another variable with the flat array, I am simply reassigning the flat array to the original one?

```
fulfilledPromises = fulfilledPromises.flat()
```

I suppose that `fulfilledPromises` is of type `string[][][]` and the .flat() type `string[][]` can't be assigned to it?

If yes, what would be the correct approach? Instantiating a new variable or creating a type union between the two?

Comment: Why not just call `flat` right after `onlyFulfilled`?